# PIL convert('ycbcr') gives different result from formula

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

**PIL version: Pillow==7.0.0**

The formula of RGB to YCbCr is from Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr

Below is a reproducible code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# use PIL library
img = Image.open('any_image_you_have_in_hand.png').convert('RGB')
img, cb, cr = img.convert('YCbCr').split()
img = np.array(img).astype(np.float32) / 255.
print(img[:48,:48])

# use formula
def rgb_to_y(img_array):
    # formula is from wikipedia
    R,G,B = img_array[0], img_array[1], img_array[2]
    return 16. + (65.481 * R + 128.553 * G + 24.966 * B) / 255.

img2 = Image.open('any_image_you_have_in_hand.png').convert('RGB')
img2 = np.array(img2).transpose((2, 0, 1)).astype(np.float32) # c,h,w
img2 = rgb_to_y(img2) / 255.
print(img2[:48,:48])
```

for my first print, result is:

```
[[0.23921569 0.23137255 0.25882354 ... 0.29803923 0.2901961  0.2784314 ]
 [0.28235295 0.27058825 0.2784314  ... 0.29411766 0.27450982 0.25490198]
 [0.30980393 0.29803923 0.28627452 ... 0.27058825 0.24705882 0.22745098]
 ...
 [0.36862746 0.3882353  0.38431373 ... 0.2901961  0.26666668 0.23137255]
 [0.34117648 0.3647059  0.36862746 ... 0.28627452 0.2509804  0.21568628]
 [0.32156864 0.3372549  0.34117648 ... 0.28235295 0.24705882 0.2       ]]
```

for second print:

```
[[0.2715234  0.2647303  0.2859449  ... 0.31916285 0.31284797 0.30334702]
 [0.30731112 0.29715002 0.30229288 ... 0.31736776 0.301333   0.2826982 ]
 [0.33021307 0.31946597 0.3087391  ... 0.29637206 0.27735332 0.25868148]
 ...
 [0.3811901  0.3966759  0.3951199  ... 0.31489903 0.2921655  0.2634269 ]
 [0.35805577 0.37632346 0.3808803  ... 0.31143683 0.28081554 0.24971604]
 [0.34024617 0.35549274 0.3586216  ... 0.30724373 0.27533928 0.23587382]]
```

​clearly it is different...and now I don't know which one to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL appears to use the following conversion from `RGB` to `YCbCr` in `src/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.c`

[image]

Comment: this is defined as the analog RGB to YCbCr, but since in computer vision we are using 8-bit image, ranging from [0,255], I think the formula for digital RGB to YCbCr is more suitable?

Comment: It's not an area of my expertise. On the face of it, your suggestion sounds very reasonable. You can supply your own color matrix coefficients to `convert()` if you wish https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert  Example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60848253/2836621